# Recuperar Text e Value do Select com KENDO MVVM

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, mvvm, telerik

preciso da ajuda de vcs, quem tiver conhecimento em `KnockoutJS`

Tenho algo assim:

```
var viewModelPessoa = kendo.observable({
    Contatos: [],
    FormContato: {
        TipoContato: -1, //Aqui vai o indice/value do select/option
        TipoContatoTexto: null, //Aqui vai o text do select/option
    },
    AddToContato: function() {
         this.get("Contatos").push({
            TipoContato: this.get("FormContato.TipoContato"),
            TipoContatoTexto: this.get("FormContato.TipoContatoTexto"),
         });
    }
});
```

E na minha pagina tenho o seguinte:

```
<select id="listaTipoContatos" data-bind="value: FormContato.TipoContato">
    <option value="-1"> Não informado </option>
    <option value="0"> Telefone Residencial </option>
    <option value="1"> Telefone Comercial </option>
</select>
```

Como faço? coloco algo como `<select id="listaTipoContatos" data-bind="value: FormContato.TipoContato,text: FormContato.TipoContatoTexto">` ?

Answer (score 1):

A sintaxe correta do bind de um select, conforme a [documentação](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/options-binding.html) do Knockout é assim:

```
<select data-bind="options: availableCountries,
                   optionsText: function(item) {
                       return item.countryName + ' (pop: ' + item.countryPopulation + ')'
                   },
                   value: selectedCountry,
                   optionsCaption: 'Choose...'"></select>
```

Não tenho experiência com o Kendo, mas imagino que neste caso você deveria passar o "Contatos" no `options`, e especificar os atributos certos para usar como `value`.